# Hide text in <h4>

Tags: text, hide

I need help too remove or hide this text

```
<h4> I want hide this text </h4>
```

I try this but this don't work:

```
$( "h4" ).hide();
```

Comment: have you included jQuery library ?

Comment: That should work fine - I suspect as @NityaKumar implies, you're missing the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#hideBtn").click(function(){
    $('h4').hide();
});
  
$("#showBtn").click(function(){
    $('h4').show();
});

$("#remBtn").click(function(){
    $('h4').remove();
});

});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button id='hideBtn'>Click to Hide H4 </button>
<button id='showBtn'>Show to Hide H4 </button>
<button id='remBtn'>Remove Permanent</button>

<h4>H4 content for hide and show </h4>
  
  </body>
  </html>
```

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("h4").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $("h4").hide();
});
</script>
  
</head>
<body>
 <h4>I want to hide</h4>
 <h5>Test</h5>
</body>
</html>
```

```
       <html>
        <head>
        <title>Title of the document</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("h4").hide();
   });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>I want to hide</h4>
         <h5>Test</h5>
    </body>
    </html>
```